# How to quote "*/" in JavaDocs

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

I have a need to include `*/` in my JavaDoc comment. The problem is that this is also the same sequence for closing a comment. What the proper way to quote/escape this?

Example:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*/".
 */
public boolean containsSpecialSequence(String str)
```

**Follow up**: It appears I can use `&#47;` for the slash. The only downside is that this isn't all that readable when viewing the code directly in a text editor.

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*&#47;".
 */
```

Comment: I like bobince's suggestion to include "asterisk followed by a slash", perhaps in parentheses after the literal "*&#47;". It's then readable both in code and Javadoc.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use HTML escaping.

So in your example:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*&#47;".
 */
public boolean containsSpecialSequence(String str)
```

`&#47;` escapes as a "/" character.

Javadoc should insert the escaped sequence unmolested into the HTML it generates, and that should render as "*/" in your browser.

If you want to be very careful, you could escape both characters: `&#42;&#47;` translates to `*/`

**Edit:**

> *Follow up: It appears I can use &#47;
>   for the slash. The only downside is
>   that this isn't all that readable when
>   view the code directly.*

So? The point isn't for your code to be readable, the point is for your code **documentation** to be readable. Most Javadoc comments embed complex HTML for explaination. Hell, C#'s equivalent offers a complete XML tag library. I've seen some pretty intricate structures in there, let me tell you.

**Edit 2:**
If it bothers you too much, you might embed a non-javadoc inline comment that explains the encoding:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*&#47;".
 */
// returns true if the specified string contains "*/"
public boolean containsSpecialSequence(String str)
```

Comment: I'd have gone for the &#x42;.

Comment: Does this bother anyone else except for me?  Now it looks good in the javadoc but it's unreadable when you're just looking at the source code...

Comment: It's not entirely unreadable. You're a programmer, right? You should at least be able to realize that it's an HTML escape code, even if you don't recognize the actual value. You can always look it up. As I said before, the point of javadoc is readability of documentation, not code.

Comment: That said, you could always embed a comment that's not Javadoc to explain it to yourself elsewhere in your code. Something like:    //  searches for "*/"

Comment: Just open the javadoc view in your IDE. They tend to be pretty awesome these days...

Comment: One note that may be mentioned is that this will not get escaped in `{@code }` blocks and if a code or pre-formatted output is desired that it must exist within a `<code></code>` block instead.

Answer (score 16):

Nobody mentioned [{@literal}](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/whatsnew-1.5.0.html). This is another way to go:

```java
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*{@literal /}".
 */
```

Unfortunately you cannot escape `*/` at a time. With some drawbacks, this also fixes:

> > The only downside is that this isn't all that readable when viewing the code directly in a text editor.

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*&#47;".
 */
```

This is the ‘right’ solution, but for readability's sake I'd probably go for:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the string contains an asterisk followed by slash.
 */
```

Comment: well, ok, but that advice isn't very useful when giving examples of shell glob patterns e.g. `foo/bar/**/baz.zip`

Answer (score 6):

Use the entity

```
*&#47;
```

In your documentation it will show up as a "*/"

Answer (score 6):

Another way I stumbled upon, just for completeness: add some HTML markup which doesn't alter the output between the * and /.

```
  /**
   * *<b/>/
   */
```

Compared to the HTML escape solution, this seems something of an ugly hack, but it also yields the right result in HTML output.

Comment: Not quite; your suggestion as it currently stands would likely violate html doctypes. If somebody were to go this route, I would suggest something like: <b>*</b><b>/</b> to make sure the tags are closed.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about that, but left it like that because it's the shortest option and worked fine in IDEA (Ctrl-Q). If not <b/>, wouldn't *<b></b>/ or *<span/>/ suffice?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you also add a line comment somewhere near saying something like

```
// *&#47; is html for */
```