# How to write */ in a javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to quote “*/” in JavaDocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631817/how-to-quote-in-javadocs)

I want to put following doc to a method:

```
Route example:

<code>
get("/users/*/{id}") -> UsersController.show(id)
</code>
```

But since there is a `*/` in the code, the javadoc will be break on that position, the java code can't be compiled.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the `*` as `&#42;` or `/` as `&#47;`