# "error: unclosed comment" in multiline comments

Tags: scala

When converting a template from Java to Scala, I've noticed the following quirk with multiline comments that can be reduced to the following snippet:

```
/**
 * /*
 */

class Blah {}
```

The above fails to compile with "error: unclosed comment", while being valid in Java.

This proves problematic, since it makes it harder to document e.g. acceptance of glob-type strings (e.g. "requires a path like `something/*.myformat`").

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is, in fact, **a feature**. To quote [Section 1.4 of the Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#whitespace-and-comments):

> A multi-line comment is a sequence of characters between `/*` and `*/`.
>   Multi-line comments may be nested, but are required to be properly
>   nested. **Therefore, a comment like `/* /* */` will be rejected as having
>   an unterminated comment.**

(emph. mine)

Fortunately, it's relatively easy to work around in the case you need it (like the glob example from the question) [by escaping the `/` or `*` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/631839/724361), netting something like:

```
/**
 * /&#42;
 */
```

which displays correctly in the generated Scaladoc.