# groovy block comment and special chars in string

Tags: gradle, groovy, comments

Gradle

```
/*

def v = "**/*.xml"

*/
```

Groovy think the `*/` inside the string is the end of block comment.

Comment: It's the same for Java. Grammar limitation.
If it's JavaDoc - you can use answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631817/how-to-quote-in-javadocs

Answer (score 3):

If you are commenting out a block of (syntactically correct) code, I find it easier to use `if(false) {...}` to avoid this problem.